# Custom magento product page

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to develop product page like below image for my store is it possible in magento 1.9.x.x?

[product page image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H99UZ.jpg)

Comment: You can achieve much of this by overriding `app/design/frontend/[path-to-template]/template/catalog/product/view.phtml` and also creating custom block at the right column.

Comment: if you know any extension then tell me so i can do it very easily.